# Inequality for positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, $B$ be positive definite symmetric matrices. such that $A \leq B$, i.e., $(A - B)$ is a negative semi-definite matrix.

Is it true to conclude that $B^{-1} \leq A^{-1}$?

(I need to prove it in order to use in the proof of a theorem in stability of control systems)

For trivial examples $A=aI$ and $B=bI$, where $a \leq b$, the above statement is true.

In addition, I think it can simply be proven for the case that $A$, $B$ commute, i.e., $(A B = BA)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If (A-B) is p.s.d then by non negativity of eigen values it can be say that (A-B)^{-1} is also p.s.d. Now we need the relation between A^{-1} -B^{-1} and (A-B)^{-1}.

Comment: @janak note that $A-B$ may be singular.

Comment: Ohh..I did the mistake. You are right.